# I had a custom Arduino Board fabricated, and I can't load it with a bootloader

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, bootloader

I've made a custom circuit board from Arduino UNO as a base, had the board fabricated, and now I'm trying to burn a bootloader.

I have ICSP headers for both the ATmega32p and the 16U2

Here is my schematic \

[image]

here is my Arduino IDE output from the burn bootloader, using another UNO.

```
         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem143301
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.

Failed chip erase: uploading error: exit status 1
```

plugging it in VIA USB doesn't show anything in my devices list either.

Power seems ok as the power LED is on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you flashed the 16U? It needs a program too in order to function as a USB interface. That's probably why it doesn't register as a usb device too. If you want something simpler, look at the FTDI chips for example as a USB interface, they don't need anything extra other than a few passives. That's what some older arduinos used.

Comment: I attempted to flash it, but it doesn't get recognized at all when plugging it in

Comment: The bootloader goes on the ATmega, not the 16U. The 16U needs a different program, I'm not sure if that is available from Arduino manufacturers. Also, make sure the atmega is powered and the ICSP header has a good connection to it. The output from avrdude looks like there is a bad connection. What kind of programmer are you using?

Comment: I'm using an UNO connected via the ICSP to attempt to burn. In my error output I was attempting the 328p

Comment: It looks like your programmer (UNO) is not hooked up correctly or the target (atmega) is not powered. I'd recommend to buy something like a USBasp programmer (super cheap) or AVRISP mk2 (not as cheap but much better). If you plan on working in with AVRs you'll find it come very handy, trust me.

Answer (score 2):

You need firmware for both AVRs.

Mega16U2 needs firmware to work as USB serial UART interface if you want to communicate between PC USB and the Mega328. It will not even show up as an USB device unless the firmware tells it what to do.

Mega328 needs the Arduino bootloader to be able to reprogram the application firmware over UART through Mega16U2.

Comment: I'm attempting to program over the ICSP pins